# Erlang list comprehension, once again

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get a list comprehension working, which intention is to verify that each element `X` in `List` is followed by `X+Incr` (or an empty list). Later, I shall use that list and compare it with a list generated with `lists:seq(From,To,Incr)`.
The purpose is to practice writing test cases and finding test properties.

I've done the following steps:

```
1> List.
[1,3,5,8,9,11,13]
2> Incr.
2
3> List2=[X || X <- List, (tl(List) == []) orelse (hd(tl(List)) == X + Incr)].
[1]
```

To me, it seem that my list comprehension only takes the first element in `List`, running that through the filter/guards, and stops, but it should do the same for EACH element in `List`, right?

I would like line 3 returning a list, looking like: `[1,2,9,11,13]`.

Any ideas of how to modify current comprehension, or change my approach totally?

PS. I'm using eqc-quickcheck, distributed via [Quviq's webpage](http://www.quviq.com/downloads/eqcmini.zip), if that might change how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your list comprehension is that `List` always refers to the entire list.  Thus this condition allows only those `X` that are equal to the second element of `List` minus `Incr`:

```
(hd(tl(List)) == X + Incr)
```

The second element is always 3, so this condition only holds for X = 1.

A list comprehension cannot "look ahead" to other list elements, so this should probably be written as a recursive function:

```
check_incr([], _Incr) ->
    true;
check_incr([_], _Incr) ->
    true;
check_incr([A, B | Rest], Incr) ->
    A + Incr == B andalso check_incr([B | Rest], Incr).
```

Comment: Yeah... Of course. Stupid me (; I guess a comprehension isn't the right tool, like André Laszlo said...

Comment: I will implement a helper function instead, like above comment mentions. Suppose that will be the easiest way!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but a list comprehension is supposed to be ["creating a list based on existing lists"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension). Here's one way to generate your list using a list comprehension without using `lists:seq`:

```
> Start = 1, Inc = 2, N = 6.
6
> [Start + X*Inc || X <- lists:seq(0,N)].
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
```

Comment: Yeah, generating the list isn't the problem. The problem is to check whether List fulfils the criteria that for each element X, the next element is X+Incr or an empty list.

Comment: Then maybe a list comprehension is the wrong tool for the job, since you're unable to look at neighboring elements?

Comment: I think you're right... Comprehension is not the right tool!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
> lists:zipwith(fun (X, Y) -> Y - X end, [0 | List], List ++ [0]).
[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,-13]
```

Then check that all elements are equal to `Incr`, except the first that should be equal to `From` and the last that should be greater or equal than `-To`.

Answer (score 0):

One quick comment is that the value `List` does **NOT** change when in the comprehension is evaluated, it always refers to the initial list. It is `X` which steps over all the elements in the list. This means that your tests will always refer to the first elements of the list. As a list comprehension gives you element of a list at a time it is generally not a good tool to use when you want to compare elements in the list.

There is no way with a list comprehension to look at successive sublists which is what you would need (like MAPLIST in Common Lisp).